# Get the value of an attribute Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

Updated Question:

```
$(this).attr("EmployeeId", 'A42345'); 

 $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: "{EmployeeId: '" + id + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
      var obj = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

      var o = obj[$(this).attr("EmployeeId")]; //<<<<undefined
```

**END UPDATE**

i am trying to get EmployeeId withitn the DOM something like this:

```
var o = obj[$(this).attr("EmployeeId")];
```

but getting `undefined`

when i debug i see the following:

```
$(this)[0].data

     data    "{EmployeeId: 'A42345'}"
```

here is my source code:

```
$.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: url,
           data: "{EmployeeId: '" + id + "'}",
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json",
      success: function (response) {
                  var obj = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

                  var o = obj[$(this).attr("EmployeeId")]; //<<<<undefined
```

Comment: You still haven't given me enough context to see what `this` is. If you are able to assign it, I'm assuming I am correct with my first answer. Did you try what I've suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is referring to your function in the example you gave. Therefore your selector isn't matching anything.

I'm guessing you are calling an ajax function from within a click handler or some other type of event handler.

Assign $(this) to a variable in the first function and reference that variable in your success callback.

```
$(el).click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: url,
       data: "{EmployeeId: '" + id + "'}",
       contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
       dataType: "json",
       success: function (response) {
              var obj = (typeof response.d) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.d + ')') : response.d;

              var o = obj[$this.attr("EmployeeId")]; //<<<<undefined
// rest of code...
```

Posting more of your code would help though..

You may also be trying to access the data you were passing in.. in which case, parse it to json, or don't pass it in as a string in the first place.. .attr won't work on `$(this)` though, as `this` is referring to the function..

`$(this)[0].data` is the function's data. Which doesn't have attributes, it's not a DOM element.

You are using some mismatched functionality, it's hard for me to figure out exactly what your intent was.. You said you are trying to get it from the DOM, but you are showing the data of the function, those are two entirely different things.

Comment: also, on an unrelated note, the use of eval is bad.

Comment: and instead of storing "EmployeeId" as an attribute, sotre it as a data- attribute..  ex. `<span data-employeeid="1"></span>` and use .data("employeeid") to access it.

Comment: you also don't need to send data as a string, `data: {EmployeeId: id},` will work just fine.

Comment: I feel that it is important to explain that in Patrick's example, $this (aka `var self = this`) is a "closure" variable which captures the object reference for use in the callbacks - those values become part of the function object that is passed around since it is declared, referenced within the inner function definition, and the identifier, `$this`, is not reassigned in an intermediate scope.

Comment: it's common to see `var that = this;` which is equivalent to uosɐſ's example of `var self = this;` in javascript, in jquery it's common to see $ before a var name to denote that is already a jquery selector, and it doesn't need to be selected again. Just so if you see any of these, next time you will know.

Comment: Looks like I was right with the first answer, did you try what I've suggested? Though you still haven't given enough context to see what `this` refers to.

Comment: what should i use instead of `eval` ?

Comment: if you return json, you should be able to just access it, if you get a string, you can parse it into json first. Are you using .net (guessing because of the .d)? That's unrelated to this question, and stackoverflow is yelling at me, so I suggest looking elsewhere on stackoverflow, or google about the proper use of eval, or post another question. I'm not saying eval won't work, there are just better and safer ways.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9973/discussion-between-patrick-scott-and-abu-hamzah)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to parse the content of `$(this)[0].data` to json first.

Maby something like this could work.

```
var jsonData = jQuery.parseJson($(this)[0].data);  
var o = jsonData.EmployeeId;
```